# How should I get a certain field from all documents in a Firestore Collection in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get information from a Firestore database and make it into an object. My current solution is to for loop through every document in the collection containing the objects then parse each field into an object in a list before returning the list of objects. The problem is I cannot figure out the correct way to get each field.

This is my code:

```
class Task {
  IconData? iconData;
  String? title;
  Color? bgColor;
  Color? iconColor;
  Color? btnColor;
  num? left;
  num? money;
  bool isLast;
  Task(
      {this.iconData,
      this.title,
      this.bgColor,
      this.iconColor,
      this.btnColor,
      this.money,
      this.isLast = false});



  static List<Task> generateTasks() {
    int length = 0;
    List<Task> tasks = [];
    _firestore.collection("tasks").get().then((snap) => {
      length = snap.size
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
      tasks.add(Task(
        iconData: Icons.person,
        title: _firestore.collection('kids').doc(i).get().then((value) => value.data()['Title']),;   //This is not working and giving me an error.
        bgColor: Color(0xffF9F9F9),
        iconColor: Color(0xffF9F9F9),
        btnColor: Color(0xffF9F9F9),
        money: 0,
        isLast: false,
      ));
    }


    return kids;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...and update the code like your requirements

```
    class Task {
      String docId;
      String iconData;
      String title;
      Color bgColor;
      Color iconColor;
      Color btnColor;
      int left;
     int money;
  bool isLast;

  Task({
    this.iconData,
    this.title,
    this.bgColor,
    this.iconColor,
    this.btnColor,
    this.money,
    this.docId,
    this.isLast = false,
  });

  factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Task(
        iconData: json["iconData"],
        title: json["title"],
        bgColor: json["bgColor"],
        iconColor: json["iconColor"],
        btnColor: json["btnColor"],
        money: json["money"],
        docId: json["docId"],
        isLast: json["isLast"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "iconData": iconData,
        "title": title,
        "bgColor": bgColor,
        "btnColor": btnColor,
        "iconColor": iconColor,
        "isLast": isLast,
        "money": money,
        "docId": docId,
      };
}

class Kids {
  String docId;
  String title;

  Kids({
    this.docId,
    this.title,
  });

  factory Kids.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Kids(
        docId: json["docId"],
        title: json["title"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "docId": docId,
        "title": title,
      };
}

Future<List<Task>> generateTasks() async {
  List<Task> tasks = [];
  List<Kids> kidsList = [];
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tasks").get();
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
    tasks.add(Task.fromJson(element.data()));
  });
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshotKids = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("kids").get();
  querySnapshotKids.docs.forEach((element) {
    kidsList.add(Kids.fromJson(element.data()));
  });
  List<Task> updatedTasksList = [];
  tasks.forEach((tElement) {
    kidsList.forEach((kElement) {
      if (kElement.docId == tElement.docId) {
        tElement.title = kElement.title;
        updatedTasksList.add(tElement);
      } else {
        updatedTasksList.add(tElement);
      }
    });
  });

  return updatedTasksList;
}
```